# The .app file generated from flutter build is 300+ MB

Tags: flutter

The flutter generate the huge size (300+mb) of Runner.app after running `flutter build ios`. The app is default counter app source code.

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem for one of my app the apk was around 20 mb and the Runner app size was around 405 mb,but when we build the archive and generate an ipa it was back to 35 mb on average for most of the ios devices.

> The release Flutter.framework now contains bitcode, which makes for a very large intermediate artifact. This bitcode is either recompiled or stripped out automatically by the process of creating a distribution IPA.[read more](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47101#issuecomment-567522077)